# Yii - Active Record Relations Has_Many Issue

Tags: activerecord, yii, has-many

Im new to Yii and am having trouble establishing AR relations.
I've had with Rails Active Record but am not able to set a simple relation in Yii.

The case in point is between 2 models, Business and BusinessDescription, where 1 Business can have N BusinessDescriptions.

Im using MySQL with MyIsam Engine and have declared a FK in BusinessDescription named business_id.

Business Relations:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
                 'businessdescription' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'businessdescription', 'business_id'),
    );
}
```

BusinessDescriptions Relations:

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
                    'business' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'business', 'business_id'),
        );
    }
```

In my website's controller in my Index action I am doing the following:

```
$business= Business::model()->findByPk(1);
$b_desc = $business->description;
$test_relation = $business->businessdescription;
```

This either gives me `Property "Business.description" is not defined.` or if I declare it in the Business model like `public $descriptin` it returns null when I *var_dump* it.

All I want it is to fetch the records from the assossiation.

Regards and thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `businessdescription` is a `HAS_MANY` relation, it will return an array, e.g. :

```
foreach ($business->businessdescription as $bdesc)
{
  echo $bdesc->description;
}
```

PS: MyIsam do not support FK, you should use InnoDB

Comment: Yes, indeed it was a MyIsam issue :(  Although I admit I was trying to do something like: `$business->businessdescription->description`, Rails style. It seems that when I do my findByPk, this will have to do: `$business->businessdescription[0]->description`. Thanks for your input and your MyIsam clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected:
This must be returning the array

```
foreach($model as $val){
echo $val->attribute;
}
```

Use like this:

```
$business= Business::model()->findByPk(1);
$b_desc = $business->businessdescription->description;
```

Comment: Weidly, this puts out: "Trying to get property of non-object". Any thoughts?